# Web form behaving differently when secure https

Tags: forms, ssl, https

I have a web form which I have recently secured with an SSL Certificate.

Since installing the certificate, the form behaves differently - when it was unsecured http it would give an error message if any required field was not filled in eg "This field is required". However, as a secured https page it doesn't give this error message any more and it is possible to submit the form whether the fields are filled in or not.

I'm a little confused because nothing else has changed other than the form page is now secured https.

Any advice on why this might be and how I could fix it would be much appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JavaScript for validation, Open the web page with either Google Inspect or Firefox Firebug, Check whether any of the java script is blocking or not... Its looks like some of the .js file is not loading properly.

If the validation are using ASP.NET validator, then there shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: "If the validation are using ASP.NET validator" or any other server-side validator (JSP/PHP/Ruby/etc).

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I downloaded Firebug, but I'm afraid as a layman in this area, I just don't have the skills to know what to do with it! This is the url to the secure form https://clevercarbuyer.com/buy.php and the unsecured version that works here http://clevercarbuyer.com/buy.php If anyone is able to shed any light that would be great, thanks. :-)

Comment: Hi, I checked, when i click "Proceed with booking", without filling out the form, i got err mssg "This field is required." in both the version.

Comment: Hi Viji. Thank you so much for the respone. Yes, with the help of my host's technical support I managed to sort the issue. I needed to put a new script in the head tag to make it work. Thanks again. M

Comment: Hi, I'm so glad that it worked. Can you please make this answer as accepted?